# Update a table with English words/vocabulary (tsv file) with dictionary definitions

Tags: r

I have a .tsv file with a list of words/vocabulary in English without a translation or dictionary definition from my Amazon Kindle and I want to update the table with each word's definition by some dictionary. There are over a 1000 words on that list and I have no way of doing this manually.

Is there any app or program that might do the trick?

If programming something is necessary I pretty good in R and a bit in Swift. I haven't found an R package that might apply.

Anyone any ideas? I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Here is a sample.
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XTGV.png)

Most of that table is blank on the right side. I'd like some sort of definition for each word in those blanks.

Comment: if you already have a dictionary with the definitions, why do you need to update the tsv? you already have it, your updated table would be a subset of the dictionary

Comment: I don't have the definitions, only the the words themselves.

Comment: Could you please post a small sample of what you have for input and your desired output?

Comment: I've added a sample screenshot. Any ideas?

Comment: there is an R package called wordnet which is a good place to start. This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239066/retrieve-synonyms-of-words-using-wordnet-for-r